# Stumped completely by "UncaughtReferenceError: X not defined at function"

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, scope, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to build a google map that takes data from a fusion table using their api and displays it on the map. I have the data displaying on the map now.

I would like to have a button that toggles the data on/off and after googling extensively I have tried to implement the solutions I found. I have the code set up almost exactly the same but am still unable to toggle the data.

I believe something is wrong with my scope because whenever I click the button it gives a "Uncaught ReferenceError: view1 is not defined" error in the Javascript Dev Console .

I have googled this as well and at first I believed that the function "toggleView1" was not defined globally so I changed it, however it still will not work... Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I am at a loss at this point.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WorkingMapTiles</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXAPIKEYXX">.   </script>
    <script>



  var view1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: '\'LatitudeLongitude\'',
      from: 'XXXfusionTableIdXXX'
    }
  });

  function init() {
    var mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(45.000, -65.000),
        new google.maps.LatLng(46.000, -64.000));
    var mapMinZoom = 14;
    var mapMaxZoom = 17;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.fitBounds(mapBounds);


    view1.setMap(map);
  }



  ////FUNCTION NOT GETTING TRIGGERED BY BUTTONS
  function toggleView1() { 
    if(view1.map) {
      view1.setOptions({map: null});
    } else {
      view1.setOptions({map: map});
    }
  }
    </script>
<style>
  html, body, #map { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
  #floating-panel { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 25%;}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="floating-panel">
    <input type="button" value="Toggle view1" onclick="toggleView1();">. </input>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `view1` only exists in `init()`

Comment: The edited version won't work either -> [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Comment: Okay now this edited version doesn't have variable shadowing.  The map loads normally with the data showing over it. And now, I click the button and the data disappears. Yay. But then when I click it again the data does not reappear. It gives a "InvalidValueError: setMap: not an js?key=XXXAPIKeyXXX:40 instance of map" error

Comment: Constantly changing your question by removing the problems is not the way how SO works...

Comment: Okay I'll change this to resolved and make a new thread if need be. Thanks Andreas!

Answer (score 0):

Originaly:

```
function init() {
  var mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(45.000, -65.000),
      new google.maps.LatLng(46.000, -64.000));
  var mapMinZoom = 14;
  var mapMaxZoom = 17;

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
  map.fitBounds(mapBounds);

  var view1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      from: 'XXXfusionTableIdXXX'
    }
  });

  view1.setMap(map);
}
```

View one is in init()'s scope because that is where is defined. Brought variable definition of view1 out of init()'s scope. Note that you may not have another definition of view1 inside of init()'s scope or there will be [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)